# Unity - Dialogue pops up

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity:

Could anybody tell me what I did wrong. I wanted to pop up a dialogue after you are nearby a charecter but somehow my code doesn't really work.

```
public class Interactable : MonoBehaviour {
    [HideInInspector]
    public NavMeshAgent playerAgent;
    private bool hasInteracted;

public virtual void MoveToIneraction(NavMeshAgent playerAgent)
{
    hasInteracted = false;
    this.playerAgent = playerAgent;
    playerAgent.stoppingDistance = 2.3f;
    playerAgent.destination = this.transform.position;

    Interact ();
}

void Update()
{
    if (!!hasInteracted && playerAgent != null && playerAgent.pathPending)
    {
        if(playerAgent.remainingDistance <= playerAgent.stoppingDistance)
        {
            Interact();
            hasInteracted = true;
        }
    }
}

public virtual void Interact()
{
    Debug.Log("Interacted");
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with it does't work: nothing pops up or the game crash/display an error?

Answer (score 1):

```
!!hasInteracted
```

It should be `!hasInteracted`, I guess